# Iterate and output dynamic table in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a python script using selenium for a horse racing software site.

The site shows a table in which horses names and odds will appear when they become an 'arb'.

When a horse is an 'arb' it will show up on the table and when it is no longer an arb it will disappear.

The script needs to make a list of all the horses that have come up throughout the day with their name and odds.

So far I have managed to get it to write out the selected 'name' and 'odds' values when I first run the script.

However I am unsure how I would code it to iterate over time, updating and adding to the list.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#Start Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/username/PycharmProjects/SoftwareBot/drivers/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://software.com/members/user/software2")

#Get Title
title = driver.title
print(title)

#Login To Page
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("johndoe@hotmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("Pass123")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Continue"]').click()

#Sleep
time.sleep(1.5)

#Find Num Of Rows
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="data_body"]/tr'))
print(rows)

#Find Num Of Columns
cols = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="data_body"]/tr[1]/td'))
print(cols)

#Open Text File
f= open("horses.txt","w+")

#Write out needed table values
for r in range(1, rows + 1):
        for c in range(3, 7, 3):
            value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="data_body"]/tr[' + str(r) + ']/td[' + str(c) + ']').text
            print(value)
            f.write(value)
            f.write("\n")

time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: I think this a bigger issue than just modifying your code to "iterate over time, updating and adding to the list". What does "over time" mean? All day? Do you plan on having your computer open all day, or do you need a build server for this? You will need some sort of external library to manage that -- this is not really a Selenium question, more like a question about timing builds.

Comment: Hi Christine thanks for your response, I am fairly new to this so as you have stated above there are probably a lot of easier options. It being open on the computer all day is fine for me at the moment as is just for personal use so the simplest option for now will suffice. So whatever I can do to essentially just run the script in the morning to keep checking for updates and recording them is what I am trying to achieve. If you have any advice on a route to progress with it would be very much appreciated

Comment: The issue with leaving the browser open all day on your computer is that the connection will likely time out either due to idle time or just due to chromedriver staying open for so long -- issues like intermittent internet connectivity will terminate the session. I have seen plenty of cases where chromedriver starts behaving unexpectedly after several hours, usually due to external network issues. It would be better to launch the browser only when you want to record data, then close it when you are finished scraping, and re-launch it later.

Comment: I think you need to look at this problem from a higher level -- this is more complicated than just adding `sleep(300)` between data pulls in your script. I recommend reading up on Python task scheduler to get started. https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-your-python-scripts-with-task-scheduler-661d0a40b279 As of now, I believe this question needs more focus to be considered in scope for stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok Christine thanks for your comments I will bare them in mind.